# How to make one button to display on the right hand corner using angular4

Tags: html, css

i have a menu bar, i am getting the menu button like this

[image]

[image]

But i need the menu bar to look like this

[image]

I tried giving css in button but i am getting scroll inside the menu bar, but i need to place the button side on the menu bar.

HTML:

```
<mat-drawer-container class="sidnav-container" autosize [class.moveLeft]="showSidenavTitle">
<mat-drawer #drawer  *ngIf="showNav" class="sidnav-sidenav" mode="side" opened="true" [ngStyle]="{ 'width.px': sidenavWidth }">
  <button (click)="changeWidth()" mat-mini-fab><img src="../../assets/images/menu.png"></button>
  <mat-list class="wd_logo" [class.decreaseLogo]="!showSidenavTitle">
    <img src="../../assets/images/logo_white.png">
    <span *ngIf="showSidenavTitle">WIREDELTA</span>
  </mat-list>
  <mat-divider></mat-divider>
  <mat-list>
    <h3 mat-subheader *ngIf="showSidenavTitle">User</h3>
    <mat-list-item routerLinkActive="activeTab">
      <a routerLink="/tracking" matTooltip="Tracking">
                <i class="fa fa-hourglass-half" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span *ngIf="showSidenavTitle">Tracking</span>
            </a>
    </mat-list-item>
    <mat-list-item routerLinkActive="activeTab">
      <a routerLink="/history" matTooltip="History">
                <i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i><span *ngIf="showSidenavTitle">History</span>
            </a>
    </mat-list-item>
    <mat-list-item routerLinkActive="activeTab">
      <a routerLink="/account" matTooltip="Account">
                <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span *ngIf="showSidenavTitle">Account</span>
            </a>
    </mat-list-item>
    <mat-divider></mat-divider>
    <h3 mat-subheader *ngIf="showSidenavTitle">Project</h3>
    <mat-list-item routerLinkActive="activeTab">
      <a routerLink="/projectHistory" matTooltip="ProjectHistory">
                <i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span *ngIf="showSidenavTitle">History</span>
            </a>
    </mat-list-item>
    <mat-divider></mat-divider>
    <h3 mat-subheader *ngIf="showSidenavTitle">Admin</h3>
    <mat-list-item routerLinkActive="activeTab">
      <a routerLink="/department" matTooltip="Department">
        <mat-icon svgIcon="hierarchy"></mat-icon> <span *ngIf="showSidenavTitle">Department</span>
      </a>
    </mat-list-item>
    <mat-list-item routerLinkActive="activeTab">
      <a routerLink="/users" matTooltip="Users">
                <i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span *ngIf="showSidenavTitle">Users</span>
            </a>
    </mat-list-item>
    <mat-list-item routerLinkActive="activeTab">
      <a routerLink="/projects" matTooltip="Projects">
        <mat-icon svgIcon="coding"></mat-icon> <span *ngIf="showSidenavTitle">Projects</span>
      </a>
    </mat-list-item>
    <mat-list-item routerLinkActive="activeTab">
      <a routerLink="/userAccess" matTooltip="UserAccess">
        <mat-icon svgIcon="key"></mat-icon> <span *ngIf="showSidenavTitle">User Access</span>
      </a>
    </mat-list-item>
  </mat-list>
</mat-drawer>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<div class="profileDiv"></div>
```

SCSS:

```
   .main {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  mat-drawer-container {
    height: 100%;
    .mat-drawer {
      position: fixed;
      height: 100%;
      background: linear-gradient(#72D2BD, #4D75B1);
      transition: width .3s !important;
      box-shadow: 3px 0px 15px 2px rgba(199, 212, 193, 1);
      button {
        position: absolute;
        background: none;
        right: 0px;
      }
      .wd_logo {
        text-align: center;
        padding: 20px 0px 15px 0px;
        img {
          width: 75px;
          height: 45px;
        }
        span {
          font-size: 24px;
          color: $white;
          vertical-align: bottom;
          line-height: 20px;
          font-family: MontserratRegular;
          text-overflow: ellipsis;
          overflow: hidden;
          max-width: 185px;
          display: inline-block;
        }
      }
      mat-divider {
        border-top-color: #579aa4;
        padding: 8px 0px;
      }
      .mat-subheader {
        font-family: MontserratRegular;
        font-size: 22px;
        color: $white;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        letter-spacing: 0.8px;
        padding-left: 30px;
      }
      .mat-list-item {
        margin: 0px 15px;
        transition: all 0.15s;
        &:hover {
          @include awesome;
          a {
            span,
            i {
              @include spanClass;
            }
          }
        }
        a {
          display: flex;
          i,
          mat-icon {
            color: $white;
            font-size: 18px;
            padding-right: 10px;
            line-height: 24px;
          }
          span {
            font-family: montserratLight;
            font-size: 18px;
            color: $white;
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

This is my full code, i tried by insreasing right and all but i get a scroll bar but i need that button to get placed, please help

Comment: Adding something like `top: calc(50% - 15px);` and `right: -15px;`? Being 15px half of the button height and width.

Comment: i get a scroll, so its not working

Comment: what do you mean by "i get a scroll "?

Comment: Please post your complete code

Comment: @Bhrungarajni [mcve]

Comment: @JuvenileSnow Any idea?

Comment: @Bhrungarajni please create a working jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is set the parent element to have a position of `relative` then when you give you button a position of `absolute` it will be absolutely positioned to the menu bar

so for example...

```
.menu-bar{
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

button{
  position: absolute;
  right: -20px; // May be different just a guess
  top: calc(50% - 15px); // This will center it vertically
}
```

what you want to do is set the right position to be `-` and then you will be able to get the desired result

Comment: Thanks for the response, i will check and update you

Comment: Sorry i get a scroll, but i want that button to get placed

Comment: Please post a working js fiddle of your problem or post more of your code.. you shouldnt be getting a scroll bar